# Why do I not get an error when running this, but I do get an error when running this `a,b := 2`?

Tags: pointers, go

I am very new to Go and a beginner to programming. I cam across this:

```
res, err := http.Get("URL_HERE")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand this? Does `http.Get` return two values? Is `err` a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `http.Get` returns two values. The documentation of `http.Get` [is here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get), and this is its signature:

```
func Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
```

`err` is a value of the `error` type, which is an interface so it could be `nil`. From [its documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error):

> The error built-in interface type is the conventional interface for
>   representing an error condition, with the nil value representing no
>   error.

I strongly suggest you start learning Go by completing the [online tour](http://package%20main), and then check out additional learning resources at https://learn.go.dev/

Comment: @user13731744: yes